# slideshow title not showing when clicking through slideshow?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, title, alt

See my demo page here: http://intelligen.info/pro%20templates/template%20grid%20center/

I am using Nivo Lightbox plugin. I am also using CMS surreal. From a previous question I posted on here ([Add the alt attribute to light box slideshow title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882041/add-the-alt-attribute-to-light-box-slideshow-title))  I got the code below to  make the title of the slideshow link to the alt attribute of the image tag instead of the title attribute of the anchor surrounding it?

```
var altText;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#nivo-lightbox-demo a').nivoLightbox({
    effect: 'fade',
    beforeShowLightbox: function () {
        altText = $($(this)[0].el).find('img').prop('alt');
    },
    afterShowLightbox: function (light) {
        if (altText!=="") $($(light)[0]).find('.nivo-lightbox-title').html(altText);
    }
 });
});
```

This works perfectly when clicking on the individual thumbnails, then the title is displayed, however if one clicks through the slideshow the title isn't displayed anymore. How do I get the slideshow to display the titles while clicking through the slideshow?

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/MH8mu/2/

Comment: I'm sure I could help, could you set up a jsFiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/MH8mu/2/

Comment: Thx, diving into code ...

Comment: The documentation says that if you want a title to be displayed, you just have to put the text you want in the title attribute of the a tag holding your image .. isn't it what you would like to achieve ?

Comment: yes, however if you look at the previous question I asked, the reason I need the alt attribute of the image to act as the title attribute of the anchor is due to using CMS surreal. So I can't put the title in the title attribute of the a. I need it to be in the alt attribute of the image so the user can edit it through the CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin was not designed do this properly but I managed to make things work without having to modify the lightbox code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var navHandler = function(element){
        if(element[0])
            element = element[0][0];
        var title = $(element).children().attr('alt');
        $(element).attr('title', title);   
        $('.nivo-lightbox-overlay .nivo-lightbox-title').html(title);
    };
    $('#nivo-lightbox-demo a').nivoLightbox({
        effect: 'fade',
        beforeShowLightbox: function(){navHandler(this.el);},
        onPrev: navHandler,
        onNext: navHandler
    });
});
```

Fiddle updated [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/MH8mu/3/)